# GoLang - types from different scopes

Tags: go

If you are getting an error like:

`interface conversion: interface {} is *purchase.User, not *purchase.User (types from different scopes)`

It appears that you are sending the correct type since the expected and actual type in the error message are exactly the same.

Comment: Could be a useful question. I went to edit for clarity but the edit queue is full @chiaDev. I suggest rewording as a question; all answer elements can go in the actual answer below.

Comment: hi @Mark thank you. do you know how I can clear the edit queue? 

Answer (score 1):

You may have created another type pointing to the *purchase.User in another package (purchase2) and that is the type your method is looking into receiving but you are sending (purchase.User)

**For example:**

in `purchase` package

```
type User struct {
    firstName string
    lastName string
}
```

in `purchase2` package

```
import purchase

type User purchase.User
```

Check which type are you referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate cause for this: you have somehow imported the package twice, with two different import paths. This is unlikely to be seen except in unusual circumstances (AST code rewriters, non-standard vendoring, etc).

If you are importing the same package with different paths, there is a very good chance that you're doing something very wrong. Stop it :P